# SQL takes more time to fetch records

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2012

I am using sql server 2012. I have one table, contains 1.7 million records. I am just selecting all record using (`select * from table_name`). But it takes 1 Hour 2 minutes to fetch.
What should i do to fetch records quickly?

Comment: These days `Select * From` is considered as gateway to P45, Never ever use this in a huge table. Did u wait for 20 minutes to check that, and also have u checked size of database `log file` after 20 minutes ?

Comment: In addition to the above comment, how many records do you have, and how large is this table?  For millions of records, you can expect the query to take minutes.

Comment: "Contains records"? I would be surprised if your table didn't contain any **rows** if it's taking 20 minute to return data from a `SELECT *`. @BHouse has the right point here though, `SELECT *` is going to be slow with large tables. If you want a "quick" query, limit the columns you're returning in your `SELECT`, or limit the rows using a `WHERE`.

Comment: Is it a base table or a view?

Comment: table contains 17 lakhs records.

Comment: One other reason for apparent slowness might be excessive locking. If your table is not very large, and yet you wait a lot for the results, check if somebody else might be holding some lock longer than necessary...

Comment: @vinGa What is "lacks"?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic, probably [lakhs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh), units of 100,000, or 1.7 million rows here.

Comment: How wide are the rows? If you are reading all 1.7M rows into memory on the client, it may be that there's not enough memory on the client machine and you are doing excessive paging.

Comment: table has 27 column and data space 298 mb and idex space 59 mb

Comment: Do you need all columns? Also, using select * is never recomended, if you for example add another column to your table/view it may break queries, packages in your etl etc.

Comment: I will use where clause to filter but that much time is expected to fetch 1.7M records ?

Comment: I have created stored Procedure to create Report.but it aslo takes more time. so i have started debugging using basic command ie. `select * from tblName`.

Comment: Log size is 4112 mb and Log Space Used 96.69%

Comment: What are you asking here, @vinGa? debugging using `select * from tblName` is just a bad idea. There is no way you have an report that requires all of your columns and rows. you wouldn't even be able to export thatinto an xlsx file...

Comment: but it takes 1 hr for 1.7M records. I think  it should take less time, so i just start with `select * from tbname` query

Comment: What is the purpose of `select * from table`? If you want to performance tune, do it for a typical query. That query is only typical if you are exporting records and there are much faster ways to do that.

Comment: Why do you think that doing a `SELECT *` is going to help...? It's not. Period. If you're trying to debug a query, then ask about that query. If your question is "How I make `SELECT * FROM [Table];` run faster?" the answer is easy: You don't; or **significantly** increase the resources of your server. This should more like your query is "I have a query (which I haven't provided), however, it is performing poorly. Thus I wanted to check why and did a `SELECT *...`. This also, performs poorly. how do I make `SELECT *...` better?" The problem isn't your `SELECT *...` it's your initial query.

Comment: Ok Thanks !!! Now i have used all filters and i have use subquery in joins but performance is slow

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is limit your Result by Using

Top(100) Result or Where Clause Your Desired Data instead of

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

This will help you get only concerning and limited data in a less amount of time.
Another thing you can do is to Get Concerning columns only which gives you desired results.
This will significantly enhance the fetching time.